# Creating procedures, using putty.exe

Tags: php, mysql, plsql, putty, procedures

I am doing an mysql php application and I need to create a procedure to make my foreign keys work fine and also to create a calendar for report purposes. However, I have been trying to create the procedures and it does not works in putty.exe which is the only software available to do my application. I researched and I did not find anything related to this. Can anyone advise if I will need extra files for putty or the way to do it?

Comment: hm... are you serious? Calling mysql procedures with ssh client?

Comment: You need some scp client like winscp, So you copy your sql file having  sql procedures to server. Then execute file from putty there.

Comment: is it not possible? what are the alternatives?

Comment: I am going to research on this.

Comment: Do You not have PHPmyadmin access?

Comment: Not, in the server I am using, but I have another server that contains it.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj Ok, I downloaded winscp. It looks basecally the same of filezilla, is it right? But, I transfer the file via ftp, is it going to be to the same location of the website ? What is the best extension for the file containing the procedure? and after I have my file in the right place, I just need to go to putty and type "./filename.extension", right?

Comment: It is sorted guys, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the mysql client to run commands against mysql. In the putty command line just run:

> mysql

You will most likely need to add parameters to the command, like the user and the password needed to connect. Check the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html) for details.

To run the script file that contains your procedure, first you have to upload the file to the server and then run it with

> mysql < script.sql

Comment: Ok, so if I transfer the file via ftp, is it going to be to the same location of the website ? What is the best extension for the file containing the procedure? and after I have my file in the right place, I just need to go to putty and type "./filename.extension", right?

Comment: See the edit on how you run script files. As for the file name, it should be the same name it has on your PC

Comment: once, I run the script files, will it be there forever and work without the need of ruining it everytime needed?

Comment: You only need to run the script once. Then the procedure is created. If you want to change the procedure, then you could edit the script that contains it and run the script again.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try now.